# Перестал работать плагин WakaTime

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, плагин

Пользовался данным плагином достаточно давно, но до недавно плагин перестал работать на любом моем редакторе кода полностью.Ошибка отсылает на файл .log, в котором содержится данный текст

> {"caller":"pkg/language/chroma.go:77","file":"Untitled-1","func":"language.detectChromaCustomized","level":"warning","lineno":1,"message":"failed to load head from file "Untitled-1": failed to open file: open Untitled-1: The system cannot find the file specified.","now":"2023-10-21T20:31:21+03:00","os/arch":"windows/amd64","plugin":"vscode/1.70.3 vscode-wakatime/24.2.2","time":1697909478.27052,"version":"v1.78.0"}

Я не понимаю что здесь написано, в чем можеть быть ошибка?

Comment: Черным по белому написано: Произошла ошибка при попытке загрузить файл с именем "Untitled-1". Судя по сообщению об ошибке, файл не может быть открыт, поскольку система не может найти указанный файл. А вот почему не может найти, куда он делся, вопрос уже к вам.